# jQuery datatable resulting in "cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" error when passing JSON url

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm running into the error

> "cannot read property 'mData' of undefined"

when I'm attempting to get a datatable to display JSON.  I'm not sure what is happening exactly, I'm unsure if it's a bad URL, bad HTML formatting, bad JSON, or something else entirely.  Here is the JSON:

```
[ 
   { 
      "cSoldBy":"Foy, Patrick",
      "dSoldDate":"\/Date(1575180000000)\/",
      "cSoldTo":"Nancy Myers",
      "cCar":"2019 Kia Soul Base",
      "nSalePrice":21000.00,
      "nMSRP":20000.00
   },
   { 
      "cSoldBy":"Santiago, Gabirel",
      "dSoldDate":"\/Date(1572584400000)\/",
      "cSoldTo":"Bram Stoker",
      "cCar":"2020 Kia Soul Base",
      "nSalePrice":20000.00,
      "nMSRP":21000.00
   },
   { 
      "cSoldBy":"Sareen, Jesminder",
      "dSoldDate":"\/Date(1569906000000)\/",
      "cSoldTo":"HP Lovecraft",
      "cCar":"2020 Kia Soul Base",
      "nSalePrice":21750.00,
      "nMSRP":23000.00
   }
]
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <table id="SalesList" class="display compact hover stripe order-column" style="width:70%">
        <thread>
            <tr>
                <th>Salesperson</th>
                <th>Sale Date</th>
                <th>Purchaser</th>
                <th>Car Sold</th>
                <th>Sale Price</th>
                <th>MSRP</th>
            </tr>
        </thread>
    </table>
```

And here is the Jquery:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SalesList').DataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/SalesPerson/saleslist/101"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

I was asked below about the URL for the JSON.  Here is the code for that:

```
        public JsonResult SalesList(int ID)
        {
            IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AutoDealer"].ConnectionString);

            List<ViewModels.DashboardSalesViewModel> SalesList = new List<ViewModels.DashboardSalesViewModel>();
            SalesList = db.Query<ViewModels.DashboardSalesViewModel>("usp_Get_DashboardSales", new { nUserID = ID }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsList();


            return Json(SalesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: What happens if you try to access that URL? Check your dev tools network tab to see if you are getting a successful response (200) or not.

Comment: I get a successful response, I'll post the code for that.

Comment: Ok good. Does the response match the JSON you posted? If you look at the datatables [example](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax), the records are within a `Data` property. Try formatting it like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/data/arrays.txt?_=1575656859358)

Comment: ok, that's interesting.  I don't know why it doesn't include the "data" portion, the jsonresult controller.json piece in the controller that I'm returning formats it for me.  I'm not sure how to get that result without manually formatting the results, which isn't a great option.

Comment: Use <thead> and <tbody> elements inside table tag instead of <thread> tag.

Comment: That's not necessary for server side data in datatables according to datatables documentation.  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax  However, I for testing I added a <tbody> and then even a set of fake lines equal to the number headers, the result was the same however.

Comment: jCruz, you were really close on what the issue was.  I needed to have the datasource be declared as '', because the default was data.  In addition to that I needed to manually declare the columns because the value names in the Model aren't the same names as the column names in the HTML.  I'll post what the solution was in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jcruz in comments pointed me in the right direction.  there were two issues overlapping:

1. the default datasource is "data".  the source can be unnamed, you just have to, in the jquery script, declare the datasource as ''.
2. The names of the values in the class are different from the names in the html.  I have to map, the names of the values to the columns by manually declaring their names.  Here is the corrected jQuery script:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#SalesList').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '/SalesPerson/saleslist/101',
                    dataSrc:''
                },
                columns: [
                    { data: 'cSoldBy' },
                    { data: 'dSoldDate' },
                    { data: 'cSoldTo' },
                    { data: 'cCar' },
                    { data: 'nSalePrice' },
                    { data: 'nMSRP' }

                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Thank you to everyone for your assistance.